# How to check if the field exists and if exists, get its value in mongodb $in?

Tags: mongodb, nosql, mongodb-query

I have the below query

```
db.getCollection('DOCUMENT1').find(                                     
{"FIELD1":           
    {                                                                   
            "$in":[
1234567,
7654321
            ]
    }
}       , "$and": [{
            "FIELD2" : { $exists : true }
    }] 
        ,{"FIELD1" : 1, "FIELD2" : 1} )
```

When I execute the above query , I get the below error:

Error: Line 9: Unexpected token :

I get only the documents that matches "Field1". Using $in, from the obtained document, I want to check if another field (FIELD2) exists and if exists, I want to display the value of that field. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Please ask clearly question

Comment: @Kiran Cyrus Ken : Did it work ?

Comment: Yes, it did work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be something like this :

```
db.getCollection('YourCollectionName').find({$and :[{field1: {$in:[1234567, 7654321]}},{field2:{$exists: true}}]},
{field1:1, field2:1, _id:0})
```

Your query has syntax errors & also `$and` is an array that takes in multiple filters, which has to be given in place of filterQuery of `.find()` . **Ex :-** `.find(filterQuery, projectQuery)`